# jquery change content in php template from file with "pages" in

Tags: php, jquery, html, onclick, zurb-foundation

I've created a php template with variables library and what not all pulled into an index page I've created a basic script with fades the page in and out on load and have got that working the next thing I wanted to do is to use my navbar links to pull formatted content into the page (as I'm using foundation 4 framework) now the code I tried is as follows

```
$(document).ready(function() {                     
    var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
    var href = $('#nav li a').each(function(){
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-5)){
            var toLoad = hash+'.html #content';
            $('#content').load(toLoad)
        }                                           
    });

    $('#nav li a').click(function(){

        var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
        $('#content').hide('fast',loadContent);
        $('#load').remove();
        $('#wrapper').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
        $('#load').fadeIn('normal');
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);
        function loadContent() {
            $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
        }
        function showNewContent() {
            $('#content').show('normal',hideLoader());
        }
        function hideLoader() {
            $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
        }
        return false;

    });
});
```

the idea is that onclick it removes the content with the wrapper displays a loading gif and then loads the page content which is stored in the link referred to in the

but its not working is just reloading the whole page . . . . i have tried reading up and it says that you can use

> You can extract from another page using the load method thus >$('#targetElement').load('page.htm #container') syntax.

and using the get function but im not to good at all this jquery is there a way I can do it in php or where am I going wrong with what I've done.

Answer (score 0):

Try this....You were calling the load, and functions inside improperly...

```
$('#nav li a').click(function(){

var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
$('#content').hide('fast',loadContent);
$('#load').remove();
$('#wrapper').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
$('#load').fadeIn('normal');
//window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);
function loadContent() {
    $('#content').load(toLoad,showNewContent);
}
function showNewContent() {
    $('#content').show('normal',hideLoader);
}
function hideLoader() {
    $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
}
return false;

});
```

Comment: thanks for the reply tried that to no avail still reloading the whole page . . .so to simplify things i took the loading bar out and 
using id for the navbar and div elements and still now working its still reloading the whole page ? just a really stupid thing to ask . . . .on the page im pulling on should it only have the <div id=content> in the page or a whole page markup

Comment: Oh....yes.....it should only have the content, no headers etc ....Like it should be only the content you wanna display, nothing else

Comment: so atm got this following advice above and below // `JavaScript Document
$('#nav li a').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault()
var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
$('#content').hide('fast',loadContent);
//window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);
function loadContent() {
    $('#content').load(toLoad,showNewContent);
}
function showNewContent() {
    $('#content').show(normal);
}
return false;

});`and take all headers our all that is on the new page is <div class="content">and all it does is load on new page no formating

Answer (score 0):

When a user clicks a link the browser by default unloads the current page and loads the page indicated by that link.

You need to prevent the default behavior of the browser, in order to do this you need to call the `.preventDefault()` method on the click event that was triggered for that link.

```
$('#your-context').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    /**
     * the rest of your code here
     */
});
```